# AllowAny permissions required for DELETE requests in DRF?

Tags: django, reactjs, authentication, django-rest-framework, token

I'm looking for some clarification here.

I have build a react app that connects to a Django Rest Framework (DRF). The app is completely private, meaning that no-one who is not authenticated can do anything. For this I have used TokenAuthentication (for now, because I think that SessionAuthentication would be more secure).

I'm struggling to understand this:

- I can authenticate and set the appropriate header (Authorization) with my token.
- I can perform GET/POST/PATCH requests with no issues
- **however: DELETE requests don't work: I get a 401 - Unauthorized error. But my header with my token is there just fine.** I'm using DELETE requests to remove objects from my database.

I have found a way to get it working: by decoration my view class with `@permission_classes((AllowAny, ))` it just works fine. But I'm not happy with this.

So, why is this?

In my settings file I have:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated', )
}
```

In the DRF documentation ([link](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/)) it says:

> DELETE requests require the user to have the delete permission on the model.

But, my user is an admin, so why do I need to explicitly add this decorator?

**What am I doing wrong? This can't be the best way to do this. And why is it working well without the decorator if I do the request with an external API client (like Postman - I use Paw)??**

For a reference, is my simplified view class:

```
@permission_classes((AllowAny, ))
class ObservationAPIView(APIView):

    def delete(self, request, test_id, observation_id, format=None):

        # see if my object exists
        try:
            obs_object_to_delete = Observation.objects.get(pk=observation_id)
            test_obj = Test.objects.get(pk=test_id)

        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            errormsg = {
                'observation id': observation_id,
                'test id': test_id,
                'message': 'Cannot delete this object. Observation ID or test ID not found.'
            }
            return Response(errormsg, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

        # it exists, delete it 
        obs_object_to_delete.delete()

        # return the test data (not the deleted object)
        serializer = TestSerializer(test_obj, many=False)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def patch(self, request, test_id, observation_id, format=None):

        # there is also a PATCH function to allow for edits. 
        # This does work well without the decorator.
```

Comment: Everything looks fine here. There is no magic - in my opinion you have some bug in the react app - that no passes authorization header on delete request. As for AllowAny - it is bad solution. Basically it allows any user (not authorized too) to perform the delete action. As I said - take a look carefully at your client code.

Comment: @opalczynski Looking at my developer tools it looks like the header is sent though, but when I inspect the request at the DRF side, the header is not longer there! But only on DELETE methods. In POST or GET methods, DRF sees that my user is authenticated.

Comment: Super strange :( Do you connect to the backend directly? Or via some load balancer (like nginx?) - maybe there are some rules that cut off the Auth header on Delete action?

Comment: not in my development environment. I use the default development server (started  with npm start) for my frontend. And the backend is running in a docker container which start a server with this command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

Comment: Looking at the logs of DRF again, it seems that my frontend app sends a OPTIONS call first (part of the preflight I suppose), my server responds with code 200 (so I suppose everything works fine) and but then no other calls follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it! There was no trailing slash in the url pointing to the delete method.

But instead of giving a 404 error or something, DRF responded with an 401 (Unauthorized) error. This made me look for errors in the authorization.

But still being puzzled by this: by setting the @permission_classes((AllowAny, )) decorator, the trailing slash does not seem to be necessary for my frontend to continue after preflight. Without the decorator (ans thus with the right permissions), React does not want to continue after preflight. If you add a trailing slash in the url, it all works fine. So what is going on here? Does the allowAny bypasses CORS? And does CORS require trailing slashes?

If someone is able to explain me this behaviour I would be very grateful.

Thanks for looking everyone!!

Answer (score 1):

**Why happening this?**
Since you are added the **`DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES`** globally, ( in `settings` ) DRF will use that ***in every class based views***.
 If you want to use extra/custom permission classes for a particular view, you could add it inside the view class with the help of **`permission_classes`** attribute as,

```
class SampleView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (MyCustomPermissionClass,)
    ....
```

---

In your case, ***you need to `override` the default behaviour for a particular method***.

**So, How to override default permission classes for a partiluar method in `DRF` way?**
The **`APIView`** class a method called **`get_permissions()`** which handle this

```
class SampleView(APIView):
    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.request.method == 'DELETE':
            return [permission() for permission in (AllowAny,)]
        return super(SampleView, self).get_permissions()
    # your code
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but I don't need to know how I can add the permission level for the delete method. I want to understand why my default permission level (isAuthenticated) is not working for DELETE methods.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar symptoms for other reasons,
Maybe the debugging story will be useful for someone else.

GET, POST, PUT - works fine, DELETE - don't work
if no "AllowAny" permission is given to everyone.

debugging of requests in views.py detected that
in the last case `request.user == AnonymousUser` and `request.auth == none`.

The reason was the incorrect syntax of the DELETE request on the frontend side
(in JS `fetch(url, {method: "DELETE", headers, body})`
curly brackets position for options was wrong),
which caused header and body loss, inc. Authorization header.